# Convert HTML with contenteditable elements to PDF with edits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need a way to convert HTML after the user edit the content editable elements to PDF with the user edits.
Please find the below code which convert the HTML page but without the user edits:

```
include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$wide=300;
$hight=300; 
$mpdf=new mPDF('',array($wide,$hight), 0, '', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9);

$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('test.html'));
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: As you create the PDF from a file, the editable part needs to be part of that file if you want to convert it to PDF. The file is located on the Server, the edits of the user are done on client side. You need to send the data edited back to the server, create your html-file but send the output to "WriteHTML" instead of back to the client.

Comment: but how to send the data edited back to the server and update the file with these edits.